# Remove iframe from string with JavaScript and Regexv

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have to programmatically remove all iframes form a string that contais raw html base on the source of that iframe.
Eg: "... "

This is in a javascript string.
I thought about using String.replace based on some regex that excludes or some other approach.

Just need an example or some ideas, hope someone can help me because I am stuck with this and can't think about a propper solution.

Eg:

```
const regex = /Some weird regex to select the iframe piece/g 
//Which I don't know how to write
// Happy to use something that removes all iFrames from the code as a quickfix regardless of the url

const raw_html = "\<html\> ... \<iframe title="title" src="prohibited_url" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"\>\</iframe\> ... \</html\>"

raw_html.replace(regex, '') 
//This would remove whatever was on that regex with an empty piece of string.
```

If anyone has any ideas, they are welcome.
Thanks in advance

I've tried something like the example above, but couldn't write a working regex expression

Comment: writing regex  in a string (at least like that) wont work. maybe this can help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-user-input-string-into-regular-expression-using-javascript/

Comment: [Dont use RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1169519) to parse an entire document. Use a HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ↓↓↓

```js
let html = '<html\> ... \<iframe title="title" src="prohibited_url" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"\>\</iframe\>       <h2>Just another element to test the regex</h2> <p1>hello</p1> ... \</html\>';
let regex = /\n*\s*<iframe.*?\\?>.*?<\/iframe\\?>\s*\n*/gi;

html = html.replace(regex, '');
console.log(html);
```

If you will ever need to remove a different element, you can use this function:

```js
function removeElementFromHtmlString(element, htmlStr) {
    return htmlStr.replace(new RegExp(`\\s*<${element}.*>(?:.*<\\/${element}>)?`, 'g'), '');
}

let html = '<html\> ... \<iframe title="title" src="prohibited_url" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"\>\</iframe\>       <h2>Just another element to test the regex</h2> <p1>hello</p1> ... \</html\>';
console.log(removeElementFromHtmlString('h2', html));
console.log(removeElementFromHtmlString('p1', html));
```